# Ninject/.NET MVC3 - Scope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm a beginner with both .NET MVC and Ninject.

Here how I get my Ninject kernel:
using Ninject;

```
public class NinjectKernel
{
    private static IKernel _Instance = new StandardKernel();

    public static IKernel getInstance()
    {
            return _Instance;
    }
}
```

Here's how I save an instance of an object I want to re-use:

```
(...) NK = NinjectKernel.getInstance();
private Game getGameInstance() {
    IGame iGame;
    try
    {
        iGame = NK.Get<IGame>(DefaultGameName);
    }
    catch
    {
        NK.Bind<IGame>().To<Game>().InSingletonScope().Named(DefaultGameName)
            .WithConstructorArgument("ColorChoiceCount", 12)
            .WithConstructorArgument("CodeLength", 6)
            .WithConstructorArgument("TurnsToBePlayed", 8)
            .WithConstructorArgument("DoubleColorAllowed", true)
            ;
        iGame = NK.Get<IGame>(DefaultGameName);
    }
    return (Game)iGame;
}
```

I want the Game object to be re-usable within a use "session", which means that if he leaves the site this instance won't be used again. But in the current situation, while debugging, when I close the application and re-launch it, I always re-get the instance of my previous "session".
I would also like to know if I won't get the same instance for multiple users because I don't want this. (users may be or may not be authentified, right now they aren't at all).

(You may also suggest my a better solution than using a try/catch there, because I'm sure there must be one, but as this works it is not a priority for now.)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any of that.  Just use Nuget to install Ninject.MVC3.  This will automatically setup the project to use the MVC DependencyResolver API, and it will create a NinjectMVC3.cs file to create your mappings.

Comment: I have install Ninject and got non NinjectMVC3.cs file. Anyway I'm still interested in the answer to my question.

Comment: @user1103990 The file is App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs

Comment: @RubenBartelink - Ahh.. it seems this was updated in the recent Ninject 3 release.

Comment: Ok, I found this file, I did not expect it to be in App_Start. But I have no clue how I'me supposed to use it, the only public thing it has are void Start() and void Close(). And will it solve my "session scope" lifecycle problem ?

Comment: @user1103990 - There should be a register services method, in there you add all your kernel bindings.  The way this works is that Ninject is plugged into the MVC DependencyResolver, so automatic constructor injection occurs in your controllers.  Just add the mapping in NinjectWebCommon.cs, then add the type to your constructor and it just works.  Read this 11 part series for more information http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html (note: it initially calls it IServiceLocator, but this was changed to IDependencyResolver which you will see)

Answer (score 0):

1. You could check this excellent & easy to follow post for the usage of Ninject with MVC 3 / 4 : http://dotnetfever.com/implementing-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-ninject-di-container/
2. I recommend you redesign your web application and avoid reusing the Game Object within a "Session". The reason is that web application is design to be "stateless", which means it shall not remember the user'data accross multiple requests. The stateless nature could help your web application with better performance and better scalability.

If you do need to remember one user's Game object as long as he is in your site, then try to build the Game Object on every request. If the building is very expensive (connecting to database eg.) then use the asp.net cache to store the object for later reuse.

In a word, use cache, not Ninject to preserve the Game Object.